# Creating a Weather App using AngularJS and OpenWeather

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ionic-framework

My task is to display the weather forecast from the API.

I have the following code, but I cannot get the data to show. I just started learning `AngularJS` and using APIs today, so any sort of help would be much appreciated! Specifically, what is wrong with my code that the weather data will not show?

This is the API I need to use:

```
 http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=KansasCity&mode=json&units=imperial&cnt=7&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f

 angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('OpenWeather', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.city = "Kansas City";
    $scope.units = 'imperial';

    $scope.change = function() {
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=KansasCity&mode=json&units=imperial&cnt=7&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f';
        $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.main = data.main;
            $scope.wind = data.wind;
            $scope.description = data.weather[0].description;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $log.error('Could not retrieve data');
        });
    };

    $scope.change();
});

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Weather App</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="OpenWeather">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Kansas City Weather</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <div class="list card">
              <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <h2>10 Day Forecast</h2>
                <p>Kansas City, MO</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item item-avatar">
                  <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
                  <p>Temp: {{main.temp}}</p>
                  <p>
              </div>
              </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Solved the problem at hand. Thanks to all

Comment: what is your question? you posted a description of your project, a link to an API, and a bunch of code, but no **problem statement**.

Comment: Also, I doubt that your question involves the science and theories behind programming, so the computer-science tag is probably out of place.

Comment: try using `$http.get()` instead of `$http.jsonp()`. Url shown works fine with a get request

Comment: I'm sorry Claies. My question is what is going on in my JS code that isn't showing the data from the openweather API.

Comment: It's still not showing with .get()

Comment: the `data` doesn't have a `main` or `wind` element.  also, you tried to bind to `$scope.main` and `$scope.wind`, but your HTML is trying to access `data` and `main`.  `data` won't work because you don't have `$scope.data`, and `main` won't work because there is no element called `main` in the data being returned.

Comment: The `main` + `wind` + `weather[0].description` parameters doesn't exist in the response. Try parsing the URL [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Why did you remove the original question?

Comment: @heyyo you need to add it as the update , but you shouldn't remove the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $http the wrong way. 
Is better and cleaner to create a request object and put the params there. Please here is the oficial docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

And here JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/doqeselile/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {
  
  var vm = this;
  
  var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';
  
  var request = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    params: {
       q: 'KansasCity',
      mode: 'json',
      units: 'imperial',
      cnt: '7',
      appid: 'bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f'
    }
  };
  
  $http(request)
    .then(function(response) {
      vm.data = response.data;
    }).
    catch(function(response) {
      vm.data = response.data;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
    <h1>{{ vm.data | json }}</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am currently refreshing my front-end skills (I am a back-end dev) - I really appreciate you showing a 'better' way of retrieving API data in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory or service for getting the information and then pass the information to the controller.

```
.factory('weatherService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q){
function getWeather () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=KansasCity&mode=json&units=imperial&cnt=7&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f')
      .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(err){
        deferred.reject(err);
      });
    return deferred.promise
  }

  return {
    getWeather: getWeather,
  };
}
}])
```

Then in your controller

```
.controller('OpenWeather', ['$scope', 'weatherService', function($scope, weatherService) {
weatherService.getWeather().then(function(data) {
      $scope.city = data;
})
```

With this you can access any data from the json file and display it in your view.

```
 <div class="item item-avatar">
    <h3>{{city.name}}</h3>
    <p>Temp: {{city.temp}}</p>
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please stop creating promises where you don't need, people is learning the wrong way.

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki why creating a promise is not required here?

Comment: $http is already a promise, you just need to return that promise.
`return $http.get('')
      .then(function(data){
        return data;
      })
.catch(function(err){
        return $q.reject(err);
      });`

Answer (score -1):

Check this for ionic 4 App that use openWeather API  http://www.offlineprogrammer.com/building-a-pwa-with-ionic-4-capacitor-temperature-city/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes